# HQL query doesn't order by other mapped entity criteria

Tags: java, hibernate, hql, hibernate-mapping

I have the following entities in a Hibernate - Spring proyect.

Member:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "member")
public class Member implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1871629487715861212L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;
    
    @Column(name = "first_name")
    private String firstName;
    
    @Column(name = "last_name")
    private String lastName;
    
    @Column(name = "ident_doc")
    private String identDoc;
    
    @Column(name = "join_date")
    private String joinDate;
    
    private String nickname;
    
    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "member")
    private MemberContact memberContact;
    
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "member", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<MemberChapterLog> memberChapterLogs;
    
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "member")
    private List<ChapterOfficers> chapterOfficers;
    
    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "contactMember", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private Chapter asChapterContact;
```

Chapter:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "chapter")
@NamedQuery(
        name = "Chapter_Get_Detailed_Members_List",
        query = "from MemberChapterLog where chapter.id = :paramChapter and active = true "+
                "order by member.lastName asc")
public class Chapter implements Serializable {
    
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -8387387246818721664L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;
    
    private String initials;
    
    @Column(name ="chap_name")
    private String chapName;
    
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "category")
    private ChapCategory category;
    
    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "contact_member")
    private Member contactMember;
    
    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "chapter", fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private ChapterContact chapterContact;
    
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "chapter")
    private List<MemberChapterLog> memberChapterlogs;
    
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "chapter")
    private List<ChapterOfficers> chapterOfficers;
```

MemberChapterLog:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "member_chapter_log")
public class MemberChapterLog implements Serializable {
    
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -643503606583240644L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;
    
    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "member_id")
    private Member member;
    
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "chapter_id")
    private Chapter chapter;
    
    @Column(name = "log_date")
    private String logDate;
    
    private String comment;
    
    private boolean active;
```

I want to get a list of the active members of certain chapter (passed as ':paramChapter'), order by their last name. When I run the named query at `chapter` (`"from MemberChapterLog where chapter.id = :paramChapter and active = true order by member.lastName asc"`) it generates the following error:

`org.hibernate.HibernateException: Errors in named queries:`

`Chapter_Get_Detailed_Members_List failed because of: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: unexpected token: member near line 1, column 105 [from dev.xarlsr.cdt.entity.MemberChapterLog where chapter.id = :paramChapter and active = true order by member.lastName asc]`

If I delete the `order by member.lastName` it works properly (without any order, byt the way).

I tried to change the mapping by changing the tables foreign keys and the ownership, but doesn't work. I tried to change the fetch type without results. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the mapping:

```
@ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinColumn(name = "member_id")
private Member member;
```

`member` is a keyword in JPQL/HQL and soft-keyword handling was only introduced in Hibernate 6, so you will need to change the name of the field to e.g. `memberAssociation` and the query condition to `... order by memberAssociation.lastName asc`